# Dictionary query

Tags: python, dictionary

Below is a function that extracts information from a database which holds information about events. Everything works except that when I try and iterate through times in rows in HTML it is apparently empty. I will therefore assume that rows.append(time) is not doing what it should be doing. I tried rows.append((time)) and that did not work either.

```
def extractor(n): 
    date = (datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=n)).date()
    rows = db.execute("SELECT * FROM events WHERE date LIKE :date ORDER BY date", date = str(date) + '%')

    printed_day = date.strftime('%A') + ", " + date.strftime('%B') + " " + str(date.day) + ", " + str(datetime.datetime.now().year)
    start_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    for row in rows:
        date_split = str.split(row['date'])
        just_time = date_split[1]
        if just_time == '00:00:00':
            just_time = 'All Day'
        else:
            just_time = just_time[0:5]
        times.append((just_time))

    rows.append(times)

    results.append((rows, printed_day, start_time, times))
```

Comment: What do you think `time` is?

Comment: time is a time e.g. 12:05:00 and times is the list of all those times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it:

replace

```
times.append((just_time))

rows.append(times)
```

with

```
row['times'] = just_time
```